# #each blog post not displaying

Tags: meteor

I have a collection that contains blog posts and I'm trying to get them to display on the page. The code below doesn't list out all the blog posts and I'm not sure why. As far as I can tell it is publishing.

Path: `blog.html`

```
{{#each Blog}}
    <p>{{details}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Path: `blog.js`

```
Template.blog.onCreated(function() {
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function(){
        var id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
        self.subscribe('blog', id);
    });
});
```

Path: `Blog mongoDB example`

```
{
  "_id": "JvLqxFisXc3PLeqSh",
  "details": "Test three",
}
```

Path: `publish.js`

```
Meteor.publish('blog', function (id) {
  check(id, String);

  return Blog.find({}); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to add a helper.

```
Template.blog.helpers({
    blogPost: ()=> {
        return Blog.find({});
    }
)}
```

Path: blog.html

```
{{#each blogPost}}
    <p>{{details}}</p>
{{/each}}
```